# Не получается использовать f-строки в другом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, f-strings

Мне нужно из файла `english.py` перенести текст в файл `main.py` (что-то типа того, что у некоторых программ есть `.lang` файлы)

То есть нужно переменную `guy` перенести в файл `english.py`

`english.py`:

```
lang = {
    'actions': 'Actions',
    'balance': f"{guy}'s Balance"
}
```

`main.py`:

```
from english import lang

guy = "Andrey"

print(lang['balance'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это не ваш случай случаем?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339121/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-f-string

и решение

```
def effify(non_f_str: str):
    return eval(f'f"""{non_f_str}"""')
```

т.е. вы берете строку из файла, оборачиваете ее в f-строковый формат и выполняете, таким образом `{}` локально заполняется

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

**main.py**

```
from english import _lang

guy = "Andrey"
lang = _lang(guy)

print(lang['balance'])
```

**english.py**

```
def _lang(guy):
    lang = {
        'actions': 'Actions',
        'balance': f"{guy}'s Balance"
    }
    return lang
```

Comment: Там проблема в том что guy я сделал для примера, тоесть там для каждого пользователя отдельно

Comment: @Penggrin и что ?